# Azure templates for storage metrics and logging

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

Our Azure DevOps implementation deploys both an ARM template and runs several powershell scripts to fully deploy our solution. Currently it is modifying the Azure storage logging and metric properties using the Azure Powershell commands Set-AzureStorageServiceMetricsProperty and Set-AzureStorageServiceLoggingProperty.

While it is perfectly acceptable to continue using these commands, we're considering adding the equivalent JSON to our ARM template. Is this possible? If so, is this documented anywhere? I've looked through the Azure resource manager template [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/), but that doesn't seem to have what I need. Any pointers or even example JSON is appreciated.

Comment: Set it up the way you want it to be configured, then look at the ARM template generated in the portal.

Comment: That's a solution, but not a great one since the ARM JSON could change without notice. At least with documentation there is the implication that the JSON format is officially supported, will not change (wishful thinking?), and I can contact MS if it is incorrect.

Comment: Unfortunately the portal doesn't seem to export the JSON for these setting (and 14 others according to the warning message), so I can't get what I need using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Here's the article talking about that:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-enable-diagnostic-logs-using-template.md#non-compute-resource-template

ARM Json couldnt change without notice (well, no one would warn YOU personally, but they have breaking changes EXTREMELY RARELY, my 3 year old arm templates still work). So there nohting to fear, really.

Comment: This looks like what I need, thanks much. Good to know that breaking changes are very rare as well!